# How to hide one tab in tab bar controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.1. I have Tab Bar app like this:

[image]

For some reasons I want to hide/delete one of the bars to receive something like this:

[image]

So, the question is: how to hide one Tab of Tab Bar?
To specify: some button pressed, one tab hides. Another press and Tab appears again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: index)
```

To add back:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.insert(newElement: viewController, at: index)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working perfectly: fast, no crash and you can even hide your own view! But can I expand my question a little bit? How to do this trick from AppDelegate?

Comment: `let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController`

Comment: Thank for your answer! But in method func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { it cause crash.

Comment: Better do like this: if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            rootViewController.viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
        }